# How to split iris dataset based on a specific external vector of values?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Suppose that we have the following vector `v` :

```
  [1] 3 3 2 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 3
 [38] 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 3 1 1 3 2 1 3 2 1
 [75] 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 1 2 3 3
[112] 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 1 3 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3
[149] 3 1
```

I need to split `iris` dataset in a list where each element is a dataframe that represent one of the `v` clusters.

I tried :

```
library(datasets)
load(iris)
data=iris[,-5]
data=data.frame(cbind(data,v) )  
print(data %>%
  group_split(v)
)
```

Is there a better solution ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `base R` solution:

```
#Code
v <- sample(1:3,150,replace = T)
data=iris[,-5]
data=data.frame(cbind(data,v) )  
#Split
L <- split(data,data$v)
names(L) <- paste0('df.',names(L))
list2env(L,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The list `L` contains all the objects based on `v` and using `list2env` can set the dataframes to environment.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help !